# Angular 5 iframe hide header and footer

Tags: angular, iframe

I'm using an iframe inside my app. The external url has a header/footer which i'd like to hide. Below is what i have so far, i've tried a number of different variations, but not having any luck using the element.remove and class of "page-footer".

HTML

```
`  <iframe #iframe id="tcsFrame" [src]="<external_url_here>" 
    scrolling="no"
    frameBorder="0" 
    width="100%" 
    height="32000px" 
    type='text/html'"></iframe>
`
```

Angular Component

```
`
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-page-conditions',
  templateUrl: './my-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-page.component.css']
})
export class TermsConditionsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let doc =  this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;

doc.document.getElementsByClassName('page-footer').style.visibility = 'none';
doc.document.getElementsByClassName('page-footer').style.diplays = 'none';


  }

}

`
```

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: At this point the page is not loaded, yet. You should try to attach to some event ( onready, onload) in the iframe document and do the same.

Comment: Thanks @Toshkata i'm already using "ngAfterViewInit".. it's the equivalent of onReady. Do you have an example?

Comment: ngAfterViewInit is a hook for your page. I think the page inside the iframe is not ready,yet. I'll try to give you an answer, later.

Comment: Are the iframe url with the same, host and port, because the same origin policy will prevent any manipulation at the dom and it will be hidden for you.

Comment: yes they will be. Currently not getting any errors regarding same origin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm giving you the answer, but you better think if this is the better way to  do that. Am assuming that you maintain the page in the iframe, it will be better to pass some parameter to url not to show the header in the first place.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const self = this;
    this.iframe.nativeElement.onload = function () {
      const els = self.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('header');
      if (els.length > 0) {
        els[0].style.display = 'none';
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! really appreciate your help. It appears to be working, heating some CORS errors now but i'll get them sorted. As per a different approach, we're currently working on passing a flag in order to hide the header/footer, but there's a few weeks delay before that's done. I need a interim solution :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I will appreciate if you mark it as an answer :)